# Using VB.net Collection class via COM returns error: "Class doesn't support automation"

Tags: vb.net, com

I have an existing VB.net class library which has a public property with a type of  VB's `Collection` class. I'm exposing the class library as a COM-object to be able to use it in Progress.

When I  access the Collection-property with an integer index (e.g. `comObj.OutputCol.Item(1)`) it works fine, but when I try to use the string indexer (e.g. `comObj.OutputCol.Item("FirstCol")`) I get the following error (from a VBScript I use for testing):

> Error message: Class doesn't support automation
>   Error code: 800A01AE

Is it possible to use the string indexer in any way via COM?

Sample code, COM-object i VB.net:

```
<ComClass(TestClass.ClassId, TestClass.InterfaceId, TestClass.EventsId)>
Public Class TestClass
    Public Const ClassId As String = "063CA388-9926-44EC-B3A6-856D5299C210"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "094ECC57-4E84-423A-B20E-BD109AEDBC20"
    Public Const EventsId As String = "038B18BD-54B4-42D3-B868-71F4C52345B0"

    Private _sOutputCol As Collection = Nothing
    Private Property sOutputCol() As Collection
        Get
            If _sOutputCol Is Nothing Then
                _sOutputCol = New Collection()
            End If
            Return _sOutputCol
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Collection)
            _sOutputCol = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property OutputCol() As Collection
        Get
            Return sOutputCol
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        sOutputCol.Add("First object", "FirstCol")
        sOutputCol.Add(2, "SecondCol")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Sample test-code in VBScript:

```
Set comObj = WScript.CreateObject("VbComTest.TestClass")
wscript.echo comObj.OutputCol.Item(1) ' Works
wscript.echo comObj.OutputCol.Item(CStr("FirstCol")) ' Gives the error
```

I have registred the dll with: `>regasm "...path...\VbComTest.dll" /codebase`

Comment: Pretty unclear how this can work at all, the VB.NET Collection class is not [ComVisible(true)].  So the error is entirely normal.  Create your own collection class, implement System.Collections.ICollection.  Use a private Collection to implement the members.

Comment: Oh yes, I had to register the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll as well (via regasm if I remember correctly). The first test, with an integer indexer, works. I have it up and running on my machine.

Comment: Ugh, that can drastically screw up a machine.  You basically set off a bomb on your machine, overwriting the existing registration of .NET Framework classes.  You can't trust anything anymore, reinstall your operating system.

Comment: That was what recommended by Microsoft documentation. But you may be right.

Comment: Here is the link to MS page about registering the VB assembly: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/316163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the problem was that the indexer is overloaded and you shouldn't use that in COM-visible interfaces: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182197.aspx

Extract from the page about what happens to overloaded methods:

> When overloaded methods are exposed to COM clients, only the first
>   method overload retains its name. Subsequent overloads are uniquely
>   renamed by appending to the name an underscore character '_' and an
>   integer that corresponds to the order of declaration of the overload.
>   For example, consider the following methods.
>
> void SomeMethod(int valueOne);    void SomeMethod(int valueOne, int
>   valueTwo, int valueThree);    void SomeMethod(int valueOne, int
>   valueTwo);
>
> These methods are exposed to COM clients as the following.
>
> void SomeMethod(int valueOne);    void SomeMethod_2(int valueOne,
>   int valueTwo, int valueThree);    void SomeMethod_3(int valueOne, int
>   valueTwo);
>
> Visual Basic 6 COM clients cannot implement interface methods by using
>   an underscore in the name.

So to use the string indexer I have to write:

```
wscript.echo comObj.OutputCol.Item_3("FirstCol")
```

(Item_2 takes an Object as parameter and will also work, if the documentation is correct).